# What are current security pactices for file upload?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, file-upload

What are the best security practices to apply when an application lets users to upload files?

In my case, i am writing these files to both database and file system.

I check for size (5 Mb) and check a list of allowed mime-types.

What are the other things I should think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

1. You also need to prevent [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).
2. If you permit sensible filetypes like .zip , .rar ,etc it's strongly recommended that you perform an antivirus scan from your asp.net app probably using a command line interface.
3. Any uploaded file will be owned by the web server. But it only needs read/write permission, not execute permissions. Sometimes it can be helpful to remove the execute permission from directories to prevent the server from enumerating files.

Additional information [here](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/12/28/8-basic-rules-to-implement-secure-file-uploads/).